# Add arguments to custom submit

Tags: 7, forms

I added an extra submit-function to my form:

```
$submit = array('_check_value_public_catalog');
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array_merge($submit, $form['actions']['submit']['#submit']);
```

So the form looks like:

```
array
  0 => string '_check_value_public_catalogue'
  1 => string 'node_form_submit'
```

But I would like to pass some arguments to my `_check_value_public_catalog` function. How do I do this?

Comment: Are the arguments you wish to pass to your submit handler elements in the original form (i.e. results)?

Comment: @Chapabu, Jep, they are!

Answer (score 9):

You can't as such but you can store the values in the form somewhere and pick them up in your submit handler:

```
function mymodule_my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['saved_value_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => 'The Value'
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_my_form_submit';

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_my_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $saved_value_1 = $form_state['values']['saved_value_1'];
}
```

Exactly the same principle applies if you're doing this in a form alter hook.

Answer (score 3):

Submit handlers have `$form` and `$form_state` automatically passed to them as arguments (`$form_state` will contain the submitted values for your form).

Assuming there are no arguments already supplied, your submit handler should look like below:

```
_check_value_public_catalog($form, $form_state) {
 //do funky stuff here
}
```

If you need specific arguments sent to the function, you could either write a different submit callback to pull the data out of `$form_state` and send it to your `_check_value_public_catalog` function, or re-write your submit function as below (before arguments are assumed).

Before:

```
function _check_value_public_catalog($foo, $bar) {
//cool stuff here with $foo and $bar
}
```

After:

```
function _check_value_public_catalog($form, $form_state) {
 $foo = $form_state['values']['foo'];
 $bar = $form_state['values']['bar'];

//cool stuff with $foo and $bar
}
```

See here for some [more](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) information.

Answer (score 3):

Form submission handlers don't use anymore custom parameters as reported in [$form['#submit'] and $form['#validate'] and $form['#process'] no longer support custom parameters](http://drupal.org/node/144132#custom-params). In  that page, which is for converting modules from Drupal 5 to Drupal 6, it is suggested to use `$form['#custom_parameter']`, where "#custom_parameter" is a string that doesn't conflict with one already used by Drupal.

```
function my_form() {
  // form definition code goes here...
  $form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_function';
  $form['#my_form_param1'] = $param1;
  $form['#my_form_param2'] = $param2;
}
```

As alternative, the arguments passed to the form builder are available in `$form_state['build_info']['args']`. (See [drupal_build_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7), which describes the values contained in `$form_state`.)
If the form builder is defined as in the following code, then `$form_state['build_info']['args']` is an array containing `"this is"`, and `"a test"`.

```
$item['mymodule/test'] = array(
  'title' => 'Test',
  'description' => 'This is a test menu.', 
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
  'page arguments' => array('node_admin_content', 'this is', 'a test'), 
  'access arguments' => array('access test pages'), 
);
```

In fact the code of [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) is the following one:

```
function drupal_get_form($form_id) {
  $form_state = array();

  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $form_id from the arguments.
  array_shift($args);
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args;

  return drupal_build_form($form_id, $form_state);
}
```

The function removes the first argument it gets, which is the form ID, and put the other arguments in `$form_state['build_info']['args']`.

Answer (score 1):

found a good way to do this by attaching the parameters to the button:

when generating from

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter
*/
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $nrbuttons = 10;
  for($i = 0; $i < $nrbuttons; $i++){
    $form['button_' . $i] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('button ' . $i),
      '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_form_submited'),
      '#attributes' => array(
         'button_index' => $i,
         'other_parameter'=>'value',
      ),
    );
  }
}

/**
* Custom submit handler
*/
function MYMODULE_form_submited($form, &$form_state){
    $i           = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'];
    $other_param = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['other_parameter'];
}
```

Comment: This is good way to achieve this. Small code, lots of buttons with values 'attached' to the buttons. Answers the OP and is flexible in other use cases.

Comment: Wow! I have not tried this out but does look brilliant to me.